# Vaadin 7 server is being called on each action

Tags: vaadin7

I have an application based on Vaadin 7. During the development and local tests all was fine but today when I rolled it out to remote environment (Amazon) I got very lagy behavior. Even it seems even when I close modal window, request is being sent to server and I got "loading" sign for a second. This is very bad user experience. Is this something I can do to improve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which type of the Amazon server instance do you have? Amazon have servers located  mostly in US area. So, if you making a tests from Europe on lowest instance type, you might expect some lags.